# Is it possible to remount a filesystem read-only, if it has open fifos?

Tags: linux, mount, fifo

If a file is still open for writing on the root file system, for example, the filesystem cannot be remounted read-only for a clean shutdown.

At least this is true for regular files.  But what about named pipes, aka fifos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Opening a fifo special file for writing, does not prevent the filesystem from being remounted read-only.

```
# unshare -rm
# mount -ttmpfs tmp /mnt
# mknod /mnt/fifo p
# exec 3<>/mnt/fifo
# mount /mnt -oremount,ro
# exit
```